# USB drive not consistently recognized in Lubuntu. Why?

Tags: usb, lubuntu

I have a Lubuntu that I have downloaded from `Wubi.exe`, and I have a very simple problem.

Most of the time, whenever I plug in my pendrive, or USB drive, which has a memory capacity of 32GB and of the make Transcend, the File manager only recognizes it for a minute, and suddenly it says, "Not a valid block device". Sometimes, it also says that there IS no pen drive.

Even if I can't fix it, at least please tell me why such a thing happens.

I'm trying to transfer a 8.11GB folder to the pen drive. And sometimes it says it's not possible. Then If I try to delete anything it prevents me from doing so saying that the file is  *Read-only* I have checked all the permissions regarding the file, and it is all set to Read and Write.

My kernel version is:

```
Linux ubuntu 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Did it work in windows?

Comment: please give details of your kernel (`uname -a`).  Also, does it make a difference if you plugin the memory stick into a USB2 or a USB3 port?  Are there any kernel messages (`dmesg`) when the device disappears?  As always - edit your question with any replies.  Thanks.

Comment: @Ubuntu Yes, it did

Comment: @fossfreedom "Linux ubuntu 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux" The details of my kernel. And, no it does not make any differences when I switch ports. No kernel messages either...

Comment: @Kitizl - does this occur on another USB memory stick?  Possibly this 32GB is faulty?

Comment: @fossfreedom The 32GB works fine in Windows XP. And I also have a 2GB pendrive that works in Lubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Your drive is faulty. If you recently purchased it, I suggest returning it to where you bought it if they will accept a return in such a case.

I've had this problem before with relatively cheap drives, though it usually happens after they have been used for some time (in heavy read/write operations or after being reformatted a number of times).

Another possible cause for this (which does not seem to be the case here) is udev, which occasionally encountered bugs with formatting USB drives in older versions of Ubuntu (and would cause this kind of error). The problem would manifest as a failed attempt to format the drive, after which it would appear that the drive was faulty. This bug has since been fixed.

**Unfortunately I don't have links to the related bug(s) at this time, but I ran into them back in 12.10 or 12.04.*

Comment: It's nearly a year since I bought the drive. What do you suggest that I must do? Also, Transcend is a very trusted brand in my country.

Comment: It could still happen with a good brand, that the drive dies after a while. Most people don't know it, but Flash Drives have a certain limit to how many times they can be read/written, before they start to "go bad". I would suggest replacing your drive.

Comment: But if it works in WinXP perfectly, why should it stop working in Lubuntu?

Comment: I have found that Windows doesn't always show up a faulty drive all that quickly. I'm not sure why, but that has been my experience. Sometimes Windows allows you to use your faulty drive indefinitely, while Ubuntu (Linux in general) finds the fault and throws an error.

Comment: But isn't that the problem here? Lubuntu does not throw an error!